# Flex remoting with amfphp fails when deployed

Tags: php, apache-flex, deployment, xampp, amfphp

So i have created this flex application that uses amfphp remoting to acess data. 
channelSet is created at runtime and i think there is no problem with that. 
The app works fine when i try to run it locally(from my computer) and i can acess it eitheir by typing localhost/app_name.html or by computerName/app_name.html.
when i try to run it from other another computer using path computerName/app_name.html remoting fails, I think the problem isn't in xampp configuration because i can use those same methods from that other computer via amfphp service browser.
so i don't know what to do how to fix it or debug it, no idea where the problem might be so if anyone has any idea or can point me in some direction please help.

this is the fault i recieve

```
[RPC Fault faultString="Send failed" faultCode="Client.Error.MessageSend" faultDetail="Channel.Security.Error error Error #2048 url: 'http://vfistri1-pc/oracle/moje/Amfphp/'"]
```

Comment: the problem was i haven't created crossdomain.xml file

Comment: +1 for updating with solution